# Parsing values to specific columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to use Pandas to parse Q26 Challenges into the subsequent columns, with a "1" representing its presence in the original unparsed column. So the data frame initially looks like this:

| ID | Q26 Challenges | Q26_1 | Q26_2 | Q26_3 | Q26_4 | Q26_5 | Q26_6 | Q26_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1,2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1,3,7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

And I want it to look like this:

| ID | Q26 Challenges | Q26_1 | Q26_2 | Q26_3 | Q26_4 | Q26_5 | Q26_6 | Q26_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1,2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1,3,7 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Can you please share the data as text format instead of an image please? It will be easy for us to review.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the range of values in `Q26 Challenges`, using [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check if the current value is contained in the string and then converting that boolean value to an integer. For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Q26 Challenges': ['0', '1,2', '2', '1,2,6,7', '3,4,5,11' ] })
for i in range(1, 12):
    df[f'Q26_{i}'] = df['Q26 Challenges'].str.contains(rf'\b{i}\b').astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```py
   id Q26 Challenges  Q26_1  Q26_2  Q26_3  Q26_4  Q26_5  Q26_6  Q26_7  Q26_8  Q26_9  Q26_10  Q26_11
0   1              0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
1   2            1,2      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
2   3              2      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0
3   4        1,2,6,7      1      1      0      0      0      1      1      0      0       0       0
4   5       3,4,5,11      0      0      1      1      1      0      0      0      0       0       1
```

Comment: I got an error about not being able to convert the boolean values into integers, but I added a line with the replace method and that worked! Thanks so much!!

Comment: @WGS1984 that's strange... what version of python are you running?

Answer (score 1):

[str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) can be used on the 'Q26 Challenges' column to create the indicator values. This indicator DataFrame can be [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)ed to include the complete result range (note column headers will be of type string). [add_prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) can be used to add the 'Q26_' to the column headers. Lastly, [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the original DataFrame:

```
df = df.join(
    df['Q26 Challenges'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
        .reindex(columns=map(str, range(1, 8)), fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('Q26_')
)
```

The [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)ing can also be done dynamically based on the resulting columns. It is necessary to convert the resulting column headers to numbers first to ensure numeric order, rather than lexicographic ordering:

```
s = df['Q26 Challenges'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
# Convert to numbers to correctly access min and max
s.columns = s.columns.astype(int)
# Add back to DataFrame
df = df.join(s.reindex(
    # Build range from the min column to max column values
    columns=range(min(s.columns), max(s.columns) + 1), 
    fill_value=0
).add_prefix('Q26_'))
```

Both options produce:

```
   ID Q26 Challenges  Q26_1  Q26_2  Q26_3  Q26_4  Q26_5  Q26_6  Q26_7
0   1              5      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
1   2            1,2      1      1      0      0      0      0      0
2   3          1,3,7      1      0      1      0      0      0      1
```

Given initial input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 2, 3],
    'Q26 Challenges': ['5', '1,2', '1,3,7']
})

   ID Q26 Challenges
0   1              5
1   2            1,2
2   3          1,3,7
```